# Depreciation Method in preferences getting errors not figuring out

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat, preferences

Hello People its hard to figure out errors when you are new and even you got negative reputation in previous question so after 2 days hard research i still don't figure out the problem .

i am learning from newboston series in eclipse and some method are depreciated but i search it its does not matter in program for now later may be remove.

here is the code :

this is my prefs class.

```
 public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}

//extra class for preference in 56 ;
        // stuck in depreciason method addpreffromresource.
}
```

i added activity in mainfiest:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidme.Prefs"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.androidme.Prefs" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and this is my menu button where i hit preference and starts my activity.

case R.id.preferences

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.Aboutus:
            Intent i = new Intent(this,AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.prefernces:
        Intent prefintent = new Intent(this,Prefs.class);
        startActivity(prefintent);

        break;

    case R.id.exit:
        finish();

        break;
        }
    return false;
}
```

and i got the errors in logcat:

```
 01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074): java.lang.RuntimeException:                         Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.androidme/com.example.androidme.Prefs}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class     java.lang.reflect.Constructor
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1424)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at com.example.androidme.Prefs.onCreate(Prefs.java:13)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     ... 11 more
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     ... 22 more
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:214)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:427)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:628)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     at android.preference.ListPreference.<init>(ListPreference.java:51)
01-25 08:55:33.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):     ... 25 more
```

i don't able to read logcat too but i show to my friend who knows he told me the error is nullpointerexception and check mainfest prefs and preferencesintent and xml . still not find problem.

here is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditTextPreference 
   android:title="EditText"
   android:key="name"
   android:summary="Enter Your name"
    />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Checkbox"
    android:key="chckbox"
    android:summary="Select this box"
    android:defaultValue="true"
   ></CheckBoxPreference>

<ListPreference
    android:title="ListView"
    android:key="listview"
    android:summary="choose one from list"
    android:entries="@+array/list"
    android:entryValues="@+array/lValue"
    ></ListPreference>
```

this is xml values. array.xml
    `enter code here`

```
<EditTextPreference 
   android:title="EditText"
   android:key="name"
   android:summary="Enter Your name"
    />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Checkbox"
    android:key="chckbox"
    android:summary="Select this box"
    android:defaultValue="true"
   ></CheckBoxPreference>

<ListPreference
    android:title="ListView"
    android:key="listview"
    android:summary="choose one from list"
    android:entries="@+array/list"
    android:entryValues="@+array/lValue"
    ></ListPreference>
```

if any other thing needed i am here and thank you in advance.

Comment: it says in the log `at com.example.androidme.Prefs.onCreate(Prefs.java:13)` and the error is from the XML, mostly the last xml in your question named `R.xml.prefs`, `Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class` check that line and tell us what it have, also in the xml it says you have a string array `android:entries="@+array/list"
    android:entryValues="@+array/lValue"` for keys and values, so do you have those arrays in `/res/values/strings.xml`?

Comment: @Yazan Yes i have array.xml file to in values. for list and lValues.

Comment: @Yazan which line from binary xml file?

Comment: waht about other notes, what is line 17 in the XML file?

Comment: @Yazan at 17 line in prefs.xml is <Listpreference.

Comment: i am not sure about this, but , you may need to set `width` and `height` for that list, and also try to remove the `+` from `entries` and `entryValue` to be like this `android:entries="@array/list"`

Comment: i remove + from entries but remain same and when i remove from entryValue it showig me error.